# Javascript Add ID to elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set the attribute ID to a group of `<div>` elements which are within a parent `<div>`.

The parent `<div>` has an ID, and some of the child `<div>` have an ID but others don't.

The HTML code would be:

```
<div id="my_parent_div">
   <div id="my_child_div_a">Here is some text A</div>
   <div>Here is some text B</div>
   <div>Here is some text C</div>
   <div>Here is some text D</div>
</div>
```

After applying Javascript/JQuery it should look:

```
<div id="my_parent_div">
   <div id="my_child_div_a">Here is some text A</div>
   <div id="new_added_id_b">Here is some text B</div>
   <div id="new_added_id_c">Here is some text C</div>
   <div id="new_added_id_d">Here is some text D</div>
</div>
```

I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('div').each(function(eq, el) {
    el = $(el);
    if(typeof(el.attr('id')) === "undefined") {
        el.attr('id', 'div-' + eq);
    }
});
</script>
```

But it will give IDs to all `<div>` without an ID in the whole HTML document. I need to set the IDs only to the child elements of `#my_parent_div` that do not have one and I would like to set specific IDs  (instead of  `id="div-10", id="div-11", id=div-12`)

I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/g5Lasysu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is `$('div')` which will target all `div` elements on the page. To make it only select `div` under `#my_parent_div` use this selector instead : `$('#my_parent_div div')`

The code will now look like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#my_parent_div div').each(function(eq, el) {
    el = $(el);
    if(typeof(el.attr('id')) === "undefined") {
        el.attr('id', 'div-' + eq);
    }
});
</script>
```

**Update:**

Answering your question on the comment

If you want to have a specific id name for each element I would say you create an array listing all the names.

`var ids = ["cat", "dog", "rat", "chicken"];`

Then create a variable which will count every time it loops so you can use that to get the name on that array on a certain loop.

**So putting it all together, will look like this :**

```
var count = 0;
$('#my_parent_div div').each(function(eq, el) {
    var ids = ["cat", "dog", "rat", "chicken"];
    el = $(el);
    if(typeof(el.attr('id')) === "undefined") {
        el.attr('id', ids[count]);
        count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you. What if the IDs were to be specific names instead of `div-1, div-2` and so on?

Comment: Very interesting. Nice approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
// select the relevant element(s),
// set the 'id' property of those elements using prop():
$('#my_parent_div div').prop('id', function (i,v) {
// the first argument ('i') is the index of the current
// element from amongst the collection,
// the second ('v') is the current value of the property
// we're accessing:

    // if the current id is an empty string (v === '') or
    // it's undefined ('undefined === typeof v)
    // we set the id to the string 'new_added_id_' plus
    // the String created from the character-code of 97 ('a')
    // plus the element's index in the collection. Otherwise,
    // if the id is set we return the existing id:
    return v === '' || 'undefined' === typeof v ? 'new_added_id_' + String.fromCharCode(97 + i) : v;
});
```

```js
$('#my_parent_div div').prop('id', function(i, v) {
  return v === '' || 'undefined' === typeof v ? 'new_added_id_' + String.fromCharCode(97 + i) : v;
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
div > div[id]::before {
  content: 'ID: ' attr(id);
  color: #f00;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_parent_div">
  <div id="my_child_div_a">Here is some text A</div>
  <div>Here is some text B</div>
  <div>Here is some text C</div>
  <div>Here is some text D</div>
</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/98wnqk09/1/), for experimentation.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).
  - [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- jQuery:

  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I can only hope to have helped! :)